# moving the image from one activity to other in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent

in my app i am using camera to capture an image and i want to send it to other activity.
following is the code which explains about the path it gets stored and how it is moved to next activity

```
  String path =  String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis());
  outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

  Intent i=new Intent();
  i.setClassName("com.rest.gis","View");
  i.putExtra("image", path);
  startActivity(i);
```

here `com.rest.gis` is the my package name and `View` is the class name where I want send the image.

now in the view class how to get these datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String path = intent.getExtras().getString("image");
```

Answer (score 1):

In another activity if you have to get data then use bundle for that.

```
    Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    String imagePath=extra.getString("image");
```